# How to add a postprocessing layer to a saved model for Google AI Platform?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am doing an project about superresolution, so I get an image as input and return a bigger image (x2, x4) as output.
I am trying to upload the model to the [AI platform](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform) but I am getting problems with the combinations GPU - prediction alternatives.

I was able to make a [custom prediction](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines) code work with no problem, the input and the output is a base64 jpg image. But I can not use the GPU machines with this kind of predictions.

I tried to [generate a Estimator from my keras model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/keras_model_to_estimator) and then create a [SavedModel for online prediction](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/exporting-savedmodel-for-prediction) but I can only define the [serving input function](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/exporting-savedmodel-for-prediction#creating_serving_input_functions) for decoding a jpg image but I can not define the equivalent function for the output so the online prediction platform is returning json files of raw images that are really big (for an input of a 13K jpg image it returns a 19MB raw image)

Is there any way of defining a postprediction steps on a SaveModel to be able to get the raw image be encoded in jpg and before answer the request instances? I would like to use GPU machines that currently are not available for custom prediction routines.